# Is the Cantor's theorem proof either more complicated than necessary, or not valid? Why not?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question about Cantor's theorem proof. So here's the proof to begin with (from wikipdia):

Theorem: Let f be a map from set A to its power set P(A). Then f:A→P(A) is not surjective and therefore card(A) < card(P(A))

Proof:

*Consider the set B={x ∈ A|x ∉ f(x)}. Now, if f is surjective, then there exists some x ∈ A such that f(x) = B. However, for any x ∈ A, then either x ∈ f(x) or x ∉ f(x). In the former case, f(x) cannot equal B because x ∈ f(x) by assumption and x ∉ B by the construction of B. In the latter case, f(x) cannot equal B because x ∉ f(x) by assumption and x ∈ B by the construction of B.*
□

Now to my understanding, this proof is either valid but more complicated than necessary, or not valid. And the fact that this is my understanding leads me to think that there's something I don't understand. Let me explain:

the set B (defined as {x ∈ A|x ∉ f(x)}) is either empty or not empty. If it is not empty, then, if I understand well, it means that there is at least one element of A that is in P(A) but not in f(x). In other words, if B is not empty, then the theorem is true and there is no need to go further.

If B is empty however, I see two possibilities: either there is an element r ∈ A such that f(r) = ∅, or there is no such element r. If there is such element r, then it would mean the proof is not valid, because it would mean that f(r) = B. But since the proof is presumably valid, I don't think there is such element r, and I would be glad if someone could give me a proof that such element r doesn't exist. This would be a proof that an element of an non-empty set cannot have the empty set as image.

If B is empty and there is no such element r, then the proof is valid. But here's the thing I don't understand: if it is already recognized that there is no element r ∈ A such that f(r) = ∅, and if it is also recognized that every power set of a set includes the empty set, then why is the above Cantor's proof needed? Wouldn't it be enough to say that, since there is no element r ∈ A such that f(r) = ∅, and since every power set of a set includes the empty set, then necessarily card(A) < card(P(A))? Wouldn't that be a sufficient and much simpler proof? If not, why not?

Answer (score 3):

If $B$ is empty and $f(x)=B$, then $x\notin f(X)$, so $x\in B$. This is impossible, so $B$ is nonempty. There is no need to include this as a separate case, however, because whether $B$ is empty or not, it's still true that either $x\in B$ or $x\notin B$. Both lead to contradictions, so $f$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 3):

> the set B (defined as {x ∈ A|x ∉ f(x)}) is either empty or not empty. If it is not empty, then, if I understand well, it means that there is at least one element of A that is in P(A) but not in f(x).

No, that is not what it means for $B$ to be non-empty. If $a\in B$, then $a$ is an element of $A$ that is not in the set $f(a)$, where $f(a)$ is some subset of $A$. It does **not** mean that $a$ is in $\wp(A)$: $a$ is an **element** of $A$, not a **subset** of $A$. In symbols, you’re saying that it means that $a\in\wp(A)\setminus f(a)$, when in fact it means that $a\in A\setminus f(a)$.

> If B is empty however, I see two possibilities: either there is an element r ∈ A such that f(r) = ∅, or there is no such element r. If there is such element r, then it would mean the proof is not valid, because it would mean that f(r) = B.

In general there could well be an $r\in A$ such that $f(r)=\varnothing$, but in that case clearly $r\in B$, since $r\notin\varnothing$, so in that case we know that $B$ is **not** empty. Thus, if $B=\varnothing$, there is no $r\in A$ such that $f(r)=\varnothing$ and hence no $r\in A$ such that $f(r)=B$.